# $wpdb query a post type within a specific taxonomy term while ordering posts by custom meta value?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, query, wpdb, meta-query

I have a custom post type 'event', a custom meta field 'event_date' and a custom taxonomy 'locations'.

I want to query `$wpdb` to retrieve posts in this way

1. posts must be of the 'event' post type
2. 'events' must be associated with a certain `$location` term within the 'locations' taxonomy
3. results have to be ordered by the 'event_date' custom meta value (which is actually a date in `yymmdd` format), compared with today's present date

I'm trying with the following query parameters (I can get the `$location` value - either ID or slug - correctly and pass to this query):

```
SELECT  $wpdb->posts.* 
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
FROM    $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
WHERE   $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
AND     $wpdb->terms.term_id = $location
AND     $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'locations'
AND     $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
AND     $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'event'
AND     $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND     $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'event_date'
AND     $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value > NOW()
ORDER   BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value ASC
LIMIT   $numberofposts
```

the query is not working; if I remove the JOIN part and the taxonomy part, it will work, ordering all the results by comparing 'event_date' meta with `NOW()` date.

I guess I'm doing it wrong with the taxonomy part...

As advised, I tried to do a `WP_Query` rather than a `$wpdb` query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'locations',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $location // location term id
        )
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',  // this meta field stores event date in yymmdd format
    'meta_value' => $today,  // this would be today's date in yymmdd format
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'posts_per_page' => $numberofposts, // this variable stores the number of posts I want to get
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
);
```

However, in this latter case, the query will return ALL the posts under the specificed post_type, regardless of any other specification within `$args` including the sorting order

I've tried using `meta_query` instead of `meta_key` but result doesn't change

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using a [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) [tax](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) and [meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) query?

Comment: uhm... I don't know if it's possible to do what I want using Wordpress function, basically I need to get something as "give me the next three events from today's date (compare meta field) which happen to be in this location (term)"). I don't know how compare a custom field value with present time while querying the posts using a wp function. If this can be accomplished elegantly using WP_Query it should be ok. The code above is supposed to run in a widget. EDIT - oh yeah, looks possible, I'll give it a try

Comment: If you work this out on your own, please add it as an answer and mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: I edited my original post, unfortunately it doesn't work yet

Comment: @Fulvio - I think you're close, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in `orderby`, and `meta_value_num` is only used as an `orderby` value, try this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'locations',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $location // location term id
        )
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',  // this meta field stores event date in yymmdd format
    'meta_value' => $today,  // this would be today's date in yymmdd format
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'posts_per_page' => $numberofposts, // this variable stores the number of posts I want to get
    'orderby'=> 'meta_value_num'
);
```

Comment: ops! 5 out of 10 turns always to be the typo... the kind debug mode cannot catch...
anyway there was also something else, I forgot to put 'order' => ASC, otherwise won't work right for my case (upcoming events), thank you very much for helping me sorting it out